# Zend Framework how to configure a router GET parameters

Tags: regex, zend-framework, get, router

URL

```
somedomain.com/?_escaped_fragment_
```

try it:

```
routes.escaped-fragment.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex"
routes.escaped-fragment.route = "\?_escaped_fragment_"
routes.escaped-fragment.defaults.controller = "index"
routes.escaped-fragment.defaults.action = "someaction"
```

but he does not see the GET parameter ?_escaped_fragment_
and run

```
IndexController::indexAction
```

Comment: Two things. Your URL has `someaction` but your pattern tries to match `action`. But this might be a copy-paste mistake since this is obviously dummy content. However `(\w)` matches only a single character. You are probably looking for `(\w)+`

Comment: the problem is not the reason, I updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ZF router operates on the path only, query string params are stripped off before the route matching occurs, so you're not going to be able to get this working easily. Your options are:

- Change your URL structure
- Rewrite this URL in .htaccess
- Extend/replace the default router to check the query string before doing the standard routing